# Recover BIOS on Lenovo U310 Touch after Windows 10 rollback

Tags: bios, multi-boot, grub, windows-10-preview

I have a Lenovo U310 Touch. Before the start of the problem, I used to have a dual boot configuration with Linux Mint 17.1 and Windows 8.1 installed side by side. I used to have a GRUB bootloader with three line items:

1. Linux Mint
2. Windows 8.1
3. System Setup.

The last one used to take me to the BIOS settings page. It was also accessible using the F2 button.

One fine morning, in a fit of madness, I decided to try Windows 10. The upgrade went smooth and I observed no problems with my dual boot setup. However, when I rolled back Windows 10 using the default rollback method provided by Microsoft, I ended up with just the Windows 8.1 bootloader (GRUB was gone).

To recover GRUB I tried to boot using my live linux USB stick but my laptop didn't use it as a boot device (and yes, I tested the USB stick on my other PCs where it worked just fine).

To change the boot priority I attempted to enter into the BIOS settings program (aka the BIOS mode) by pressing F2 but pressing F2 simply used to bring back the Windows 8.1 bootloader. This was the first time I realized that the Windows 10 rollback had wiped the BIOS loader. And yes, F2 is the right key and I also tried Fn + F2.

Nonetheless, I managed to boot from the Disk0 (using PC Settings > Recovery > Advanced Options) from within Windows 8.1 itself. That brought me to my Linux Mint installation from where I recovered my original bootloader using boot-repair (ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair). This bootloader looked like what I used to have before (with a "System Setup" menu item in the boot menu). As mentioned previously, that menu item always used to bring me to the BIOS settings program. Now, it simply brings back the GRUB loader again.

Therefore, I am led to believe that wherever the BIOS settings program was had been overwritten by the Windows 8.1 bootloader and then subsequentally by GRUB.

I have tried downloading the BIOS recovery driver from Lenovo's website but it says that I must contact Technical Support to get the BIOS recovery program. Their Technical Support is unreachable (I have been trying for over a week now).

How can I get the BIOS recovery program back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a button on the side, left of the power button, press that and your laptop will boot into settings menu. Here, you can choose whatever boot options that are available for your laptop.